# Prove: As $n$ grows if $a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges so does $\frac{a_n}n$

Tags: calculus

> Let there be a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_{n+1}-a_n\rightarrow c\in \mathbb{R}$.
>   Prove that $\frac{a_n}{n}\rightarrow c$.

By definition there exists $n_0$ : $n\ge n_0$ such that $|(a_{n+1}-a_n)-c|<\epsilon$ that is $a_n+c-\epsilon<a_{n+1}<a_n+c+\epsilon$.

That step should bring me to $a_{n_0}+(n-n_0)(c-\varepsilon)<a_n<a_{n_0}+(n-n_0)(c+\varepsilon)$ but I can not see why

Comment: Let there be a sequence such that... what? Half your question is missing.

Comment: @5xum Judging from the title, this was just a grammatical problem.

Comment: it is a general proof, no more info was given on $a_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Cesàro in disguise.

Your concrete question follows by induction on $n-n_0$ (once you add the missing "There exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$" to your lax "by definition"). In other words, we show the

**Claim.** Let $n_0$ be such that $$\tag1|a_{n+1}-a_n-c|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Then for all $m\in \mathbb N$ we have $$\tag2a_{n_0}+m(c-\epsilon)<a_{n_0+m}<a_{n_0}+m(c+\epsilon)$$

*Proof.* (By induction)
The case $m=1$ is jsut $(1)$ with $n=n_0$.
Assume $(2)$ holds with $m$ replaced by $m-1$, i.e.,
$$a_{n_0}+(m-1)m(c-\epsilon)<a_{n_0+m-1}<a_{n_0}+(m-1)(c+\epsilon).$$
Then using $(1)$ with $n=n_0+m-1$ we obtain
$$ a_{n_0+m}<a_{n_0+m-1}+c+\epsilon<a_{n_0}+(m-1)(c+\epsilon)+c+\epsilon=a_{n_0}+m(c+\epsilon)$$
and likewise
$$ a_{n_0+m}>a_{n_0+m-1}+c-\epsilon>a_{n_0}+(m-1)(c-\epsilon)+c-\epsilon=a_{n_0}+m(c-\epsilon),$$
i.e., $(2)$ holds for $m$ as well. $_\square$

Comment: Thanks, but I can not still understand how the induction was built and where did the $(n-n_0)(c-\epsilon)$ came from

Answer (score 0):

Cesàro theorem gives that, assuming $b_n\to c$, $\frac{b_1+\ldots+b_n}{n}\to c$ follows.

If you take $b_n$ as $a_{n}-a_{n-1}$, you have:
$$ \frac{a_n-a_0}{n}\to c $$
hence:
$$ \frac{a_n}{n}\to c. $$